# Disabling 'leaving site' popup mid form

Tags: javascript

So I basically want to remove the leaving site popup, If the user fills in a postcode that isn't in a list, I display a sweet alert, which essentially counts down 2 seconds and redirects them to a "Sorry we couldn't help page". The problem is, is that then triggers the "Leave site, changes you made may not be saved" popup, which looks a little bit silly.

I've tried looking around and trying to use beforeunload, but I still get the popup. Is there any way to disable it, or automatically confirm it?

I've tried things such as:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', onbeforeunload);
function onbeforeunload(e) {
    console.log('>>>> onbeforeunload called');
    e.returnValue = "false";
};
```

and

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

But both of these still pop up the popup window...

Comment: The proper counterpart to `addEventListener` is `removeEventListener` …

Comment: @04FS but you still have to give the reference to the handler added with `addEventListener`. If it's something outside OP's control, then it's not going to be easy to just call `removeEventListener`. So, the question is - how is the event handler that stops navigating away added?

Comment: @VLAZ yes, of course. Based on the code they have shown, I assumed `function onbeforeunload` was actually their own handler.

Comment: You need to give us more information about how that `the changes you made might not be saved` popup works. Are you using a library? How does that library know you have changed the form? Surely there is a way to reset that form?

Comment: I'm not using a library for that alert, it's just the default alert that's built in to browsers-- I have also tried using the .reset() javascript method on the form but I still got that popup.

Comment: @Stuart did you ever solve this problem? I'm facing exactly the same problem. I also .reset() all forms in the page.